# PHP display href in form from query

Tags: php, mysql, onclick

I have this code which displays all my products with a price range of $0-$25 great on left side of my webpage with the count number beside it like so.

$0-$25 (12)

```
 <?php 
$sidebar_price ="";
$price_sql = mysql_query("SELECT *,COUNT(sale_price) FROM products WHERE subcategory =      
'Shirts' AND category = 'Women' AND (sale_price BETWEEN '$00.00' AND '$25.00') GROUP BY   
(sale_price BETWEEN '$00.00' AND '$25.00')");


$prCount = mysql_num_rows($price_sql);
if ($prCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($price_sql)){

    $sale_price = $row["sale_price"];

    $sidebar_price .= '<div id="sidebar"><label><form action="?"method="REQUEST"><input type="checkbox" name="sale_price" value="'.$sale_price.'" 
 onClick="submit(); return false" ' . (isset($_REQUEST['sale_price']) && $_REQUEST['sale_price']==$row['sale_price'] ? 'checked="checked"' : '') . ' /><font 
 size="-2"><a href="?sale_price='.$sale_price.'">$0-$25 ('.$row["COUNT(sale_price)"].')</a></font></form></label></div>';

 }
  }
 ?>
```

How do I get it to work for the href and onclick?

When I click on the href or onclick it will only display the products with prices for example just $24.99 and not all the products between $0.00-$25.00 like $24.99, $22.6, 19.35, etc..

If it is not clear enough I will try to explain further.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your query shouldn't be working! try to execute it on the DB. It has errors in it~

Comment: your query has syntax error, so it will not work at all, html looks very strange (why do you need form, checkbox and link), what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't know why but it works perfect except for the a href. I have the same code for colors and there is no problem there because I don't have to search the database for BETWEEN. It's for my side bar so if a customer clicks on the the $0-$25 it will return all the products in the sale_price column between $0-$25 from the database

Answer (score 0):

you use an underscore in `$sale_price = $row["sale_price"];` but a hyphen in`.$sale-price.`.  you may also be setting `$sale-price` somewhere else, couldn't say.

Comment: `$sale-price` is not a valid variable name in PHP, it's an expression: "take variable `$sale` and subtract (`-`) the constant `price` from it.

Comment: Sorry it was an error while typing on here. It was suppose to say <a href="?sale_price='.$sale_price.'">. I have edited the error on my question. Thanks for noticing it